# Why does my modal stop working after I leave a component and enter it again?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two components, one of them has a modal that shows after the user clicks a button. That modal has a `material table` that displays some data. The first time I run my application, I go to the component that has the modal, click the button and am able to see the rendered table even if I close and reopen my modal infinitely.

However, if I leave the component that has the modal, go to the one in which there is no modal, re-enter the component that has the modal, click the button and open the modal, the data in the `material table` will only be displayed (rendered) on odd button clicks, even clicks don't show any data on the table...

The data passes correctly and the table's data source is populated, it just doesn't render for some reason.

I pass the `material table` data from the component without modals to the component with the modal via a service and from the component with the modal to the modal itself via `@Input` event. Every time I click the button, the `@Input` event is correctly triggered and the `material table` is populated.

I've tried `ChangeDetectorRef`'s `detectChanges()` but had no success.

The component without the modal doesn't seem to be affecting anything, but "destroying" (leaving) the component that has the modal is so I will only show the code from that component and the modal.

**MyComponent.component.ts**

```
private newProductRequest = [];

private onNewProductRequest(el: any) {
  $('.modal').modal('hide');
  this.newProductRequest = {...el};
  $('#createNewProductRequestModal').appendTo("body").modal('toggle');
}
```

Everything is working as intended in this component, the data I send is the correct data and it successfully reaches the modal.

**MyComponent.component.html**

```
<m-new-product-request #createNewProductRequestModal [data]="newProductRequest"></m-new-product-request>
```

**MyModal.component.ts**

```
private products = [];

@Input('data')
set data(data: any) {
  if (data !== undefined || data !== "") {
    this.products = data;
    this.setProducts();
  }
  //this.ref.detectChanges();
}

constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.onModalHiddenEvent(this);
  this.setTableDataSource();
}

private setProducts() {
  this.onModalHiddenEvent(this);
  this.orders = [];
  for (let key in this.products) {
    this.orders.push(this.products[key]);
  }
  this.setTableDataSource();
}

private setTableDataSource() {
  this.dataSourceOrders = new MatTableDataSource(this.orders);
  this.dataSourceOrders.paginator = this.ordersPaginator;
}

private onModalHiddenEvent(self) {
  $('#createNewProductRequestModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**:

So what I noticed is that if I leave the component in which I have the modal and re-enter it, the modal isn't being properly destroyed because if I now return to the component with the modal and open it, I open a new modal and the old one... Why does this happen?

Comment: Why don't you use material dialog component? https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: Because I'm not allowed.